# Setting up SAML for Rocker.Chat (SP) with GSuite (IDP)

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, rocket.chat, idp, google-gsuite

I have an instance of Rocket.chat running on an Ubuntu server, and I am trying to configure SAML on Rocket.chat (SP) and GSuite (IDP) so that I can enable login to Rocket.chat with GSuite identities.

After several rounds of going through the documentation of rocket.chat and gsuite and testing, I am out of ideas. I would really appreciate if someone could write some instructions on how to setup it up, or point to good documentation, guides, videos about SAML on Rocket.Chat.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of debugging, looking at the source code, reading the documentation of SAML I managed to figure it out.

The steps are too long to list here so instead I summerised the needed steps in this post on my personal blog... with screenshots and references:

https://blog.jarrousse.org/setting-up-saml-for-rocker-chat-with-g-suite/

I appreciate any comments and suggestions.